# Cross reference section and page number

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I'd like to refer to a section of my document in a cross-reference, using the title of the section *and* the page number:

> In this document, we talk about foo (Discussing all the Foo, p. 36).

I know I can do this by inserting a cross-reference to the section with "Heading Text":

[image: cross-reference]

then type "p. " and then insert *another* cross-reference to the same section, this time with a page number.

But this can't be the right way to do this? I've heard something about field codes, but couldn't find an API describing how this mini-language works.

Any guidance?